# How to know which http request response belongs to which event

Tags: angular

I have a table whose data is fetched from an api and am showing that table using ngfor and keeping a track of each table row using index i

This logic will break if the http request doesn't complete in the order - the one which comes first will be the first one to get completed.
Is there any better way to handle this in angular ?

My logic.

Html template

```
<tr *ngfor="let row of rows; let i=index;">
<td>
<div (click)="delete(i)">delete row></div>
<div *ngIf="deleting[i]=="true">Show Loader</div>
</td>
<tr>
```

Typescript

```
    delete(index) {
            //adding true to the specific index which was clicked to 
      show loader based on condition
            this.deleting.splice(index, 0, true);

        //keeps track of the sequence of clicked row
            this.sequence.push(index);

        callback function and api request to delete row() {
        another call back function (){
        //to fetch new data so that view updates after deletion

        //after success response 
        //delete the value at that index and add null in its place
        deleting.splice(this.sequence[0], 0);
        deleting.splice(this.sequence[0], 0, null);

        //first element is always the first one which was inserted update it 
        by deleting the first element.
        sequence.splice(0,1);
        }
   }

}
```

Comment: You can push the deleted indexes into an observable and subscribe to them for maintaining order. Check out the `concatMap` operator to maintain the order and handle the req/res.

Comment: what problems are you having when they don't happen in order? Is it deleting the wrong element?

Comment: The delete function assumes that the sequence is always first come first completed. So if user clicked index 2 first and then 3 and if 3 gets completed first then wrong item will get deleted on callback success

Comment: index is not reliable for add/remove, so you should not delete by index, instead by id.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be a good idea to delete in sequence because if one of your deletes ends up taking a while all deletes that are made after will never show. Another downside, as you have noticed, is that indexes can change. When the indexes change it can mess with your showLoading as well as deleting the wrong values.

There is a couple things you could change to make it not matter what the sequence that you receive the responses. Say your data structure for the row looks something like this:

```
{
    id: string,
    name: string,
    someOtherData: any
}
```

You could add a property that tracks if it is being deleted or not ->

```
{
    id: string,
    name: string,
    someOtherData: any,
    isDeleting: boolean
}
```

Then change your delete function to take in the row that is being deleted as opposed to the index (as this can change). Assuming that rows is an array, you can utilize [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) or [lodash's findIndex](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#findIndex) to get the current index once the response is received and then delete it. Your delete method would then look something like this:

```
delete(row) {
    row.isDeleting = true
    // api request to delete row
        // on success
            row.isDeleting = false;
            const index = _.findIndex(rows, row);
            // delete the value at this index and add null in its place
}
```

Then change your html to look something like this:

```
<tr *ngfor="let row of rows;">
<td>
<div (click)="delete(row)">delete row></div>
<div *ngIf="row.isDeleting === true">Show Loader</div>
</td>
<tr>
```

If you don't want to change the data structure because it isn't easy for you to change you would have to make sure you check if the property exists AND then check that it is true. Then the delete method I showed above would still work the same:

```
<tr *ngfor="let row of rows;">
<td>
<div (click)="delete(row)">delete row></div>
<div *ngIf="!!row.isDeleting && row.isDeleting === true">Show Loader</div>
</td>
<tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello you can handle subscribe error. Its my working example for you:

```
    this.ch_subs = this.ch_serv.getSignals().subscribe(
      data => { console.log(data);},
      error => { console.log('Error: ', error) },
      () => {this.loading = false; });
  }
```

Good luck!